# What to study if i want to record the whole screen activity with voice and canvas on screen to write anything by touch?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

i want to create an android application which can record the current screen and can record the user voice with the option to give user to draw anything on the screen. Can anybody tell what should i study to do it ? I am just learning the android development with flutter and dart. Any help in this is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

**The Voice Interaction API**

In 2015, Google released a new version of Android called Marshmallow. Marshmallow included the Google Voice Interaction API for developers. Google’s Voice Interaction API connects voice control to all apps on a device that support it. As a result, a user can make a request and it will be fulfilled with any app that’s able to do so. Then the user can control that app using voice commands.Here is link for reference.

https://www.mobindustry.net/how-to-implement-voice-interactions-into-your-android-app/

Here is some link and example for adding voice capbilities in your android app.

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/voice-interaction/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0

https://towardsdatascience.com/creating-a-voice-recognition-calculator-android-app-869a515bf6d1

Comment: @Kabir thanks for your response but my question is not about controlling or commanding the app through voice, instead i want to record the voice and drawing created by user as a video.